# How do I prevent google web crawler from reading a single page as two different pages

Tags: html, .htaccess, seo

I have a web page say **example.com/blog/news.php** which I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

in the `.htaccess` file to hide the file extension. But google crawler reads **example.com/blog/news.php** and **example.com/blog/news** as two different pages. Please how do I prevent this, I tried to redirect the **news.php** page to **news** but it returned an error message saying to much redirect or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 301 redirect your `.php` URLs to the new (`non-php` ) format using the following rule and this way Google will only index your new URL.

Put the following right bellow `RewriteEngine on` and before your existing rules :

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```